# Android text resize on layout

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I wanted text to be as large as possible and fit on one line, as well as change on orientation to
fit and update. Is this a good way to do this in compose?

```
@Composable
fun CurrentTime(color: Color) {
    var now by remember { mutableStateOf(LocalDateTime.now()) }
    var textSize by remember { mutableStateOf(0.sp) }
    var fitSet by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    val localDensity = LocalDensity.current
    val fontScaleFactor = LocalDensity.current.fontScale

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        flow {
            while (true) {
                emit(LocalDateTime.now())
                delay(16) // allot changes for 60fps
            }
        }.collectLatest { time ->
            // Update the UI with the new time
            now = time
        }
    }

    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .onSizeChanged {
                if (!fitSet) {
                    val columnWidthDp = with(localDensity) { it.width.toDp() }
                    val text = now.format(formatter)
                    var fontSize = TextUnit(100f * fontScaleFactor, TextUnitType.Sp)
                    var result = Paint()
                        .apply {
                            this.textSize = fontSize.value
                        }
                        .measureText(text).dp

                    while (result > columnWidthDp) {
                        fontSize.value
                            .dec()
                            .also { value ->
                                fontSize = value.sp
                            }
                        result = Paint()
                            .apply {
                                this.textSize = (fontSize * fontScaleFactor).value
                            }
                            .measureText(text).dp
                    }
                    textSize = fontSize
                    fitSet = true
                }
            },
        style = TextStyle(fontSize = textSize, textAlign = TextAlign.Center),
        text = now.format(formatter),
        color = color,
    )
}
```

My Github for this...https://github.com/Richard19Perez77/TimerWithColor

I think it is working as long as you set a high enough starting dp value for instance I had to update the 100f dp to 200 for a larger device. I would like a better estimating starting dp.

Answer (score 0):

Using a binary search would allow you to efficiently cover a larger range of values.

Comment: nice, TY I like that idea. I was looking to see about passing the value from parent layout or in a custom layout. But I think a binary search is great idea for isolating the value as an improvement.

Comment: Sure yeah I mean if that seems to be working then it will converge much much faster than a linear search even if you pick an absurdly too large starting value